# XSLT: process the same element several times

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I would like to know if the following XSLT (1.0) is fine. I have an XML schema that defines an element `a` that may contain elements `b`, `c` etc. However, `a` may recursively occur in `a`.

I provide templates for `a`, `b` etc.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">

        <!-- matches also a nested <a>-->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>      

        <!-- matches only nested <a> (this has already been matched before) -->
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>                
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for nested <a> -->
<xsl:template match="a">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Given the following XML, each `a` inside an `a` gets processed two times:

```
<a>

    <b> .... </b>

    <a><b> ... </b></a>
</a>
```

Like this, I can actually append a nested `a` after the `a` it occurred in:

```
<a>

    <b> .... </b>


</a>

<a><b> ... </b></a>
```

I would like to know if this is valid XSLT 1.0 and expected behaviour or rather a hack that should be replaced by something else.

Comment: The crucial part missing in your description is this: do you want to handle all `a` elements the same, regardless on which level of hierarchy the may be?

Comment: No, I want to handle all nested `a` specially. So I could just concatenate all the `a` to one another and get rid of the nested `a`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "*concatenate all the `a` to one another and get rid of the nested `a`.*" Perhaps you should post a less abstract example and explain what are you actually trying to achieve here. Anyway, to handle the nested `a` differently than the top-level one, see the second  example in my answer.

Comment: Move a nested `a` after the `a` it occurred in so in the end you have one sequence of `a` each of which contains no nested `a` anymore. Sorry but if I try to explain in which context I use this it would take even more time ... Thx, for your advice.

Comment: Note that if you move the `a` elements that are children of the root `a` and make them siblings, your output will not be well-formed XML.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that `a` is not the root element. So all of it can be enclosed by `z` or something.

Comment: Then we need a way to identify the top `a` and construct a match pattern that will match it and no other `a` elements - for example: `<xsl:template match="z/a">`. -- Please review this: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical case (with many exceptions), you would process the nodes recursively, traversing the tree from root to leaves. Then your stylesheet would be a structured along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:template>
```

In order to handle the root `a` differently, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="/a">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <!-- do some other stuff here -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
    <!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:template>
```

---

See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model

---

### Added:

To perform the transformation shown in your edited question - i.e. to move the `a` elements that are children of the root `a` element and make them siblings of the root element, you would do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="b"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the result:

```
<a>
   <b> .... </b>
</a>
<a>
   <b> ... </b>
</a>
```

has two root elements and therefore is not a well-formed XML document.